# Parsing with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
#from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2

req = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.grupodpa.es')


soup = BeautifulSoup(req)
for link in soup.findAll("a", email=True):
    print link["email"]
```

Not getting printed the email address on that page, nor any error. Do you know what's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code, the email address is just not enclosed in an "a" tag. Probably to prevent scraping the email address by spammers.